# Emacs opening and saving encoding

Tags: emacs

I have a Perl source file in utf-8 encoding, LF ending. It contains English and Chinese characters. The questions are:

1.When I open file, the encoding is windows-1251-unix. I have to run these commands:

```
Alt-x revert-buffer-with-coding-system
> Coding system for visited file (default nil):
utf-8-auto-unix
> Revert buffer from file file_name.pl?
y
```

How to automatically open it in utf-8-auto-unix?

2.When I edit the file and try to save it, Emacs gives me a question:

```
> Select coding system (default raw-text):
utf-8-auto-unix
```

How to automatically save the file in utf-8-auto-unix? And get rid of the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could add this comment to the top of the file:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Comment: I made it like this, cause the 1-st line must be given to Perl:  
`#!/usr/bin/perl  
# -*- coding: utf-8-auto-unix -*-  
`
It worked, thx!

Answer (score 4):

Use `describe-variable`(<kbd>C-h v</kbd>) to examine the variable `current-language-environment`; follow the `customize` link and set it to "UTF-8".